# Merge two objects into array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have two objects something like this and need to combine them and create an array.

```
        var firstData = {
          label: "Out",
          data: [
            {
              value: 2,
              title: "20-06-18 09:00",
            },
            {
              value: 5,
              title: "20-06-18 08:00",
            }
          ]
        }

        var secondData = {
          label: "In",
          data: [
            {
              value: 4,
              title: "20-06-18 09:00",
            },
            {
              value: 8,
              title: "20-06-18 08:00",
            }
          ]
        }
```

The result Should be an array like this an array of object where you combine the title with labels "In" and "Out".

```
        var result = 
        [
          {
            title: "20-06-18 09:00",
            data: [
              {
                value: 4,
                label: "In",
              },
              {
                value: 2,
                label: "Out",
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            title: "20-06-18 08:00",
            data: [
              {
                value: 8,
                label: "In",
              },
              {
                value: 5,
                label: "Out",
              }
            ]
          },
        ]
```

Can anyone help, please? I will try to post a fiddler example soon. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of `reduce` to achieve your task:

```js
var firstData = { label: "Out", data: [ { value: 2, title: "20-06-18 09:00", }, { value: 5, title: "20-06-18 08:00", } ] };
var secondData = { label: "In", data: [ { value: 4, title: "20-06-18 09:00", }, { value: 8, title: "20-06-18 08:00", } ] };

var result = Object.values([firstData, secondData].reduce((acc,elem)=>{
  elem.data.forEach(({value, title})=>{
     acc[title] = acc[title] || {title, data:[]};
     acc[title].data.push({value, label:elem.label});
   });
  return acc;
},{}));

console.log(result);
```